# Using sklearn ColumnTransformer function. What do the paremeters do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

can anyone please explain the parameters passed into ColumnTransformer

```
Column_Trans=ColumnTransformer([('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],remainder='passthrough')
```

I specifically have no intuituve idea of what [0] is doing as when I change the value I get errors that dont make sense. I also think that 'passthrough' grabs the columns we didnt specify and encodes then but i dont understand how it doesn't grab columns that aren't categorical values.

Comment: where did you find this code?

Answer (score 1):

[ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data) is designed to apply different data transforming function to multiple columns consecutively. It works on `arrays`, `sparse matrices`, and pandas `DataFrames`. The result of each transformer is concatenated to form a single feature space. The class definition is:

```
class sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer(transformers, 
                                        remainder='drop', 
                                        sparse_threshold=0.3, 
                                        n_jobs=None, 
                                        transformer_weights=None)
```

**`transformers`** takes list of tuples consisting of *`(name, transformer, column(s))`*.

- *`name`* is user specified name for a transformer
- *`transformer`* is a transformer from [data transformation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html) library by sklearn.
- *`column(s)`* is list of index(es) or column name(s) you wish to apply the specific *`transformer`*

**`remainder`** can take two values `drop` or `passthrough`. The remaining index(es) or column(s) of the input are either dropped or included as they appear respectively.

---

Now, reflecting back on your question,

```
 Column_Trans=ColumnTransformer([('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],
                                remainder='passthrough')
```

- transformers is `[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])]`

  - **encoder** is the `name`,
  - [OneHotEncoder()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is `transformer`
  - `column 0` values will be used to perform OneHotEncoding.

Therefore, the final output will concat OneHotEncoded output of column 0 and the remaining columns of the input as you passed **passthrough** in your `remainder`.

---

Example:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 2.3, 2.1],
              [1.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.2]])

ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], 
                       remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit_transform(X)

# Here, One Hot Encoding is performed on each row of X on the first columns of 
# each row independently, concatenating last two columns as they originally 
# appear in input

>>> array([[1., 0., 1.0, 2.3, 2.1],
           [0., 1., 0.4, 0.6, 1.2]])
```